# libxml2 on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xpath, html-parsing, libxml2

I'm trying to parse HTML file with libxml2. Usually this works fine, but not in this case:

```
<p>
    <b>Titles</b>
    (Some Text)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                …Something1...
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="top">
                …Something2...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
```

I do this query to get the first `<td>`

```
//p[b='Titles']/table/tr/td[0]
```

but nothing is returned because libxml think that `<table>` tag is not a child of a tag `<p>` and following him.

And finally the question WHY?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation of the problem and an easy fix/solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using HTML or XML parser? AFAIR, HTML allows only inline elements inside `<p>` (you cannot put `<table>` in `<p>`), so that it auto-closes `<p>` tag after seeing `<table>` tag (in HTML, you don't have to close every tag). So, your HTML is roughly equivalent to (attributes omitted):

```
<P>
  <B>Titles</B>
  Some text...

<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>...Something1...
    <TD>...Something2...
</TABLE>
```

Try using XML parser form libxml instead of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //p[b='Titles']/table/tr/td[0]
> ```

**The error is in the indexing. XPath uses 1-based indexing**.

The corrected XPath expression is:

**`//p[b='Titles']/table/tr/td[1]`**